MTV's Liquid Television animated short
Can anyone please tell me the name of the animated short from Liquid Television that seems to be about the "advance" of civilization on primitive culture?  It's basically a satire and has really great Hawaiian  background music.
I remember it shows Europeans (pilgrims maybe) arriving in their ship on a tropical shore and the natives go from being happy and free to having to wear ties, etc.  I also remember a factory popping up and belching smoke out of the smokestacks.   Bombs fall later on and everything goes bad.
It is among the best animated shorts I've ever seen.  I found it on YouTube previously and forgot to save it.  

Your description doesn't exactly match, but it seems to roughly fit "Black Hula" (

).
